# Facebook API callback on response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with the Facebook API. I may not be going the about this the best way, but here is what I've got.

I have a array of request_ids, which I need to convert to user Ids.
I have a while loop which queries the request ids and gets the user id.

```
function (response) {
    var requestsToSend = new Array();
    var i = 0;

    while (i < response.request_ids.length)
    {
        FB.api('/'+response.request_ids[i], function(res){
            requestsToSend[i] = res['to']['id'];
        });
        i++;
    }
    console.log(requestsToSend[0], requestsToSend[1], requestsToSend[2], requestsToSend[3]);
}
```

This works fine. However, when I echo the returned ids (console.log) they are undefined, because the `FB.api` hasn't yet returned the values/responses.

Is there any way to fire the `console.log` only once the `FB.api` has returned values?
I don't really want to set a timer to fire the function.

Comment: i think res is an object and you are using res as an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iv fixed the issue but not very happy with the solution

```
    function (response) {

            var requestsToSend = new Array();
            var i = 0;
            var arry = new Array();


                        FB.api('/'+response.request_ids[0], function(res){
                            if(typeof res['to'] != 'undefined'){
                                useResults(res['to']['id']);
                            }
                        });

                        FB.api('/'+response.request_ids[1], function(res){
                            if(typeof res['to'] != 'undefined'){
                                useResults(res['to']['id']);
                            }
                        });

                        FB.api('/'+response.request_ids[2], function(res){
                            if(typeof res['to'] != 'undefined'){
                                useResults(res['to']['id']);
                            }
                        });

                        FB.api('/'+response.request_ids[3], function(res){
                            if(typeof res['to'] != 'undefined'){                
                                useResults(res['to']['id']);
                            }
                        });

                function useResults(value){
                    arry.push(value);
                    timeToFire(arry);
                }

                function timeToFire(arry){

                    if(arry.length == response.request_ids.length){
                        //console.log(arry);
                        playTheGame(arry[0], arry[1], arry[2], arry[3]);
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your console.log call in the response function:

```
function (response) {
    var requestsToSend = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    while(i < response.request_ids.length) {
        FB.api('/'+response.request_ids[i], function(res){
            requestsToSend[i] = res['to']['id'];
            console.log(requestsToSend[i]);
        });
        i++; 
    }       
}
```

Comment: I know that your suggestion works, however it doesnt help me. I know what the values are that are being returned, but I need to use them once they are all returned

Comment: so start by defining an array to store them, something like:

var finalRequests = []

Then replace the console.log code in my example with:

finalRequests.push(requestsToSend[i])

When the code drops out the bottom of the while loop, you'll have an array of requests ready to use.